# Combining dataframe columns of different lengths in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, cbind

I tried cbind and merge, but both did not work for me so far, merge didn't work because the column "realtime_period" has different dates and it merges the dates which I do not want.

I'm looking for the new dataframe to have NAs where there is no data, and given the dates of the 2 data frames, the NAs should be all at the top for the shorter column. I also tried adding a column for id# which got close but merged the columns starting from the top and all the NAs were at the bottom instead of at the top where I needed them to fill in for the missing values. If I could somehow start the row id from bottom to top and merge by row id that would work but has not figured out how to do that.

```
#list will get bigger later
 list1=list("AWHMAN","AWHNONAG")

#loop to get the 2 data frames
for(vari in list1){
  temp1=get_alfred_series(vari,"value",realtime_start = "1967-12-01", observation_start = "1967-12-01")
  final= aggregate(value~realtime_period, temp1, tail, n=1)
  names(final)[names(final) == 'value'] <- tolower(vari)
  assign(tolower(vari), final)
}

#Then I have this but the last part won't work, as merge gives the wrong output (i cant merge by realtime). 

masterlist_test2=awhman
for(vari in list1){
  fin=tolower(unlist(vari))
  tmp <- get(fin)
  masterlist_test2=merge(masterlist_test2,tmp, by="realtime_period", all = TRUE)
}
```

I need to take both "value" columns and merge them filling all the rows starting from the bottom and whatever is not filled due to the differing sizes just NAs which should be at the top of the dataframes.